# Identifying uninitialized pointer

Tags: c++, visual-studio, g++, qt-creator, clang++

Considering:

my class.h

```
class MyClass
{
    Var* var;
public:
    MyClass();
};
```

my class.cpp

```
MyClass::MyClass()
{
    if(var) {};
}
```

Is there any compiler, or compiler flag, that will tell me I forgot to initialize var, `Var* var = nullptr;`?

I tried Microsoft (Visual Studio 2019) and MinGW compilers on Qt Creator (Qt 5.15.2), passing `-Wall` flag to the compiler and seen nothing telling me about that.

So the above was on Windows. And the following I tried on macOS:

```
class MyClass
{
    int* var;
public:
    MyClass();
};

MyClass::MyClass()
{
    if(var) {}
}

int main()
{
    MyClass a;

    return 0;
}
```

While compiling with

```
g++ -Wuninitialized main.cpp -o main
```

and

```
clang++ -Wuninitialized main.cpp -o main
```

I see no warning, even with `-Wall`. Why?

```
g++ --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin21.3.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin


clang++ --version
Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin21.3.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Comment: `-Wall` (specifically `-Wuninitialized`) works fine in gcc: https://godbolt.org/z/hqbe5rPEY

Comment: And with `-Weffc++` (an old but not forgotten option) you'll even get the advice to initialize it in the member initializer list: https://godbolt.org/z/o5Gv1Pn8r

Comment: Cool! Maybe Qt Creator is someway ignoring my `Wall`. And what about Microsoft  compiler, should I use `Wall` on it also?

Comment: @paddy, I just tried it on macOS, can't see any warning.

Answer (score 1):

With Visual Studio and the Microsoft C++ compiler, I suggest compiling your code at **warning level 4** (`/W4`).

If you are using the IDE, in Solution Explorer right click on your project and select *Properties*.

Then select *C/C++* | *General*, and choose Warning Level 4, as shown below:

[image: Setting Warning Level 4 in Visual Studio 2019 IDE]

However, testing your case with VS2019, I got this warning message even at warning level 3:

> Warning   C26495  Variable 'MyClass::var' is uninitialized. Always
> initialize a member variable (type.6).

Comment: I'm using Microsoft compiler with Qt Creator actually, and on it I see `-W3` in the `cl` line, however there is no warning.